# Hashtable conditional statement in Expression

Tags: powershell, math, expression, conditional-statements, hashtable

I'm currently trying to extract information from a System.Object[] but I wanted to only get `Col1` and `Col2` out of this `$var` because it has a lot of unnecessary columns.
Setup:

```
    $var = 
   ..     Col1  Col2     
   ..     1     2147483648    
   ..     2     524288000 
   ..     3     268435456000     
   ..     4     268435456000
```

Desired:

```
   $res= 
   ..     Col1  Col2          Col3
   ..     1     2147483648    2 GB
   ..     2     524288000     500 MB
   ..     3     268435456000  250 GB 
   ..     4     268435456000  250 GB
```

I am able to get the desired Col3 with my code below:

```
foreach($t in $var)
{
    if($t.Col2% ([math]::pow(1024,3)))
    {
        $t.Col2/([math]::pow(1024,2))" MB"
    }
    else
    {
        $t.Col2/([math]::pow(1024,3))" GB"
    }
}
```

however, this just shows Col3 and not the other columns, what I wanted was to have some sort of hashtable from selecting the columns and using a column expression but I am not able to get anything if I put a conditional statement with an IF and an ELSE inside the expression in the code below:

```
$var| Select `
@{`
    l='test';`
    e=`
        {`
            if($_.Col2% ([math]::pow(1024,3)))`
            {`
                $_.Col2/([math]::pow(1024,2))"MB"`
            }`
            else`
            {`
                $_.Col2/([math]::pow(1024,3))"GB"`
            }`
        }`
}
```

My main goal is to extract these columns and bulk insert them into a table in SQL, but I am unable to make the expression with ELSE work but if i only specify the IF condition then it seems to work.

I'm wondering if this is somehow a limit for the IF-ELSE statement inside an expression for a hashtable in powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a `ScriptProperty` to your objects to calculate this, and then you would call it like a regular property. Defining a script property uses `Add-Member` and a scriptblock, but uses `$this` instead of `$_` to refer to current object.

```
$var | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name DisplaySize -Value {
        if($this.Col2 % ([math]::pow(1024,3)))
        {
            $this.Col2/([math]::pow(1024,2))"MB"
        }
        else
        {
            $this.Col2/([math]::pow(1024,3))"GB"
        }
    }
} -Force

$var[0].DisplaySize
```

Also just so you know, PowerShell includes shorthand syntax for KB/MB/GB/etc.:

```
1MB  # equivalent to writing 1048576
3TB  # equivalent to writing 3298534883328
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Solution 1, with column builded in select,  condensed
$var | select *, @{N="DisplaySize";E={ "{0} {1}" -f @(if($this.Col2 % ([math]::pow(1024,3))) {($this.Col2/1MB), "MB"} else {($this.Col2/1GB), "GB"} ) }}

#Solution 2, with column builded in select, explain
$var | select *, @{N="DisplaySize";E={

    if($this.Col2 % ([math]::pow(1024,3))) 
    {
        "{0} MB" -f ($this.Col2/1MB)
    } 
    else 
    {
        "{0} GB" -f ($this.Col2/1GB)
    } 

}} 

#Solution 3, with column builded, logique to take 2 columns
$var | select *, @{N="DisplaySizeMB";E={$this.Col2/1MB}}, @{N="DisplaySizeGB";E={$this.Col2/1GB}}
```